# Add the Autoincrement _id column

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey i made a whole app without adding an autoincrement column but now i need this column to specify the max id so i created my database in my mainactivity like this.How can i modify this to add the autoincrement _id column ?

```
 db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("testDB2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2(mac VARCHAR,mdp VARCHAR,obj VARCHAR);");
```

I don't want to create a seonc java classs only for the database because i did all the code like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2(autoincrement_id INTERGER **PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT**,mac VARCHAR,mdp VARCHAR,obj VARCHAR);");
only primary key can be autoincrement

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter the `sqlite` table to add `_id` column as primary key after table created.

What you should do is creating a new table, then copy the old data to the new table.

See the [faq](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q11) from [sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org)